# Recovering from a chown -R /

Tags: permissions, filesystems, recursive, chown

I've made today the greatest error on my server using root user:

```
chown -R 33:33 /
```

instead of `chown -R 33:33 .` within some webroot folder.

Well, this brought `ssh` down. I made it this far to get it working again, so far `apache`, `mysql` and `php` are still working, but I don't know if I ever restart them, or if the server will fail upon restarting.

Is there any "index" or package which will enable reverting these permission to the right / previous ones?

Here is the console output which help me realize and abort that operation:

[image: chown errors]

Can I do anything to recover?

Comment: What distribution?

Comment: here is an example how to deal with this, but none of the solutions will be a 100% reliable and production ready: http://superuser.com/questions/132891/how-to-reset-folder-permissions-to-their-default-in-ubuntu

Comment: Well that's a debian7 having some AMI image ( setup into aws ), so I basically have a 6 month old backup for it, all /var/www rsynced && gitted, so it isn't a big problem for me yet .. having added www-data group for root user .. things are basically working. This accident is yet a big test for me to clone the previous setup into another instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, no chance. You have to reinstall the system.

There are lists in the internet, how to re-`chown` (or `chmod`) the filesystem, but you can never cover **all files**. Those are attempt to solve this without reinstalling. But, I'm sorry for the bad news; The only correct solution is reinstalling, even if you aborted the command after a while.

The system may not even boot anymore. Most of the services probably don't start anymore.

---

I think, every system administrator had to learn that the hard way. That's why I have a some rules for myself:

1. Always when doing a command with `-R`, re-read it at least 3 times, before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then:
2. Read it again.
3. Sure?
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (and keep the fingers crossed).

Comment: `rpm` and `deb` based systems can provide file lists for installed packages, so it should (theoretically) be possible to derive the ownership:group and permissions for each file managed by a package. That's probably >95% of the system files.

Comment: @roaima I know, but that's not a clean solution, just an attempt. There are file (for example in apaches htdocs), which are in no package. Such files will be overseen by package lists.

Comment: Agreed. Whichever route the OP takes (reinstall or fix up) it's going to be painful.

Comment: provided a backup can be made, a reinstall would be faster than chowning file one by one.

Comment: In your rules, you may add: 0. can I make this operation with a less powerful user? and 3. Is my last backup up to date?